# Convert my CV to LaTeX: how to stretch text blocks vertically to fill page and color the headings

Tags: spacing, color, vertical-alignment

I am trying to convert my CV below to latex. Currently I have manually created it in Inkscape. I have already managed to get the headings and footers right:

Code:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{ihorange}{RGB}{241,98,55}

\setmainfont{Ubuntu Light}
\newfontface\footerfnt[LetterSpace=2.1]{Sansation}
\newfontface\headerfnt{Sansation Bold}

\newcommand\contactinfo{\fontsize{8pt}{8}\selectfont\headerfnt My address \\ postal code and city \\ telephonenr }

\newcommand\footertext{\fontsize{10pt}{15}\selectfont\footerfnt e: email@address /// w: www.ebsi.te /// skype: skyphandle /// twitter: @twitterhandle}

\newcommand\ColTopRule{%
{\noindent\color{ihorange}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}}

\newcommand\ColBotRule{%
{\noindent\color{ihorange}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}}

\newcommand\Header{%
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\contactinfo}%
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{%
\hfill\includegraphics[height=25.409pt]{ihlogo}}}\par\vskip1ex%
\par\ColTopRule\par}

\newcommand\Footer[1]{%
\ColBotRule\par
\noindent
\hbox{\footertext}
}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\Header}
\fancyfoot[C]{\Footer}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{70pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

But I'm struggling howto do the content. A typical cv-entry looks like this:

**position**
**@ company/organisation**
*period of time*
description of the job

What I want to achieve is that:
1) It all stays on 1 page
2) Space between textblocks are evenly distributed in each column from top to bottom of page
3) textblocks fill each columns vertically
4) I can control the color of each heading
5) If possible make use of a CV package that can be modified to look like this

[image: My CV made with Inkscape and pixelated]

Comment: First of all, do you know the document class `europecv`, `moderncv` or `simplecv`?. May be is not exactly that you have in mind, but maybe enough considering the effort to develop another template.

Comment: I'm fairly familiar with those. However, I think it will be more work customizing them so they will look like my original CV then starting afresh?

Comment: @fran Could you please add hyperlinks to the on line class documentation of `europecv`, `moderncv`, ad `simplecv` in your comment?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, the three are in [www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/) (Just add one class name to this URL to jump  directly).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: JFYI Comments can only be edited within 4 minutes.

Comment: @Speravir Thanks. I didn't realise this.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for your answer and hyperlinking it. I think the links are useful for readers who aren't familiar with the packages.

Comment: @grrrbytes irrelevant question/comment: in what way did you pixelize text in the above screenshot? Can we produce this kind of distortion automatically in LaTeX?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: not that I know of. Just simply did it with a pixelate filter in Gimp...

Comment: @grrrbytes Thank you for your time replying. It would be nice to have a LaTeX method to automatically re-produce this kind(s) of effects for selected parts of a document.

Comment: Ah, by the way, apologies: I didn't really notice your question while attracted by the screenshot! I've done a similar CV for myself using the simplecv (in LyX). I am confident that you can achieve what you are after with it. I use(d) the `multicol` package. And most of the points you put in question are easily done -- have a look at *simplecv.pdf* (ehmmm... can't trace it -- you need to compile [simplecv.dtx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/simplecv/simplecv.dtx) I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `moderncv` or friends for this job. However, this should help you to get started (though it will not answer your all questions). Fitting everything in one page should be done manually.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%--------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ihorange}{RGB}{241,98,55}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*}

\pagestyle{empty}
%--------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}%
%--------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\renewcommand\columnseprulecolor{\color{yellow}}
%--------------------------------------------------
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
\noindent
My name \\
My address\\
My home\\
My city
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}%
My name \\
My address\\
My home\\
My city
\end{minipage}%
\par
\noindent{\color{ihorange}\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{red}{\#}] {{\Large\color{red}{\bfseries About me}} \\ \lipsum[1]}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{blue}{\#}] {{\Large\color{blue}{\bfseries Work experience}} \\ \lipsum[2]}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{green}{\#}] {{\Large\color{green}{\bfseries Other experience}} \\ \lipsum[3]}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{magenta}{\#}] {{\Large\color{magenta}{\bfseries Education}} \\ \lipsum[4]}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{yellow}{\#}] {{\Large\color{yellow}{\bfseries Skills}} \\ In sleeping and eating and resting}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{green!30!blue}{\#}] {{\Large\color{green!30!blue}{\bfseries Honors \& Awards}} \\ 
      Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, in-
        terdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vi-
        tae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante.
        Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie
        non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros,
        malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, so-
        dales cursus, magna.}
  \item[\Large\bfseries\color{red!40!green}{\#}] {{\Large\color{red!40!green}{\bfseries Interests}} \\ Eating and sleeping}
\end{itemize}
%\columnbreak
\end{multicols}
\vspace{-.5cm}
\vfill
\noindent{\color{ihorange}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\noindent
My name \hfill My street \hfill My city\\
My phone \hfill My fax \hfill My mail
%--------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this definitely helps me on the way. You even got my skills and interests correct. Many tnx!

Comment: @grrrbytes: hehe. Thanks. I was trying to reduce space for those items. ;)